# First-order logic with finitistic approach

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic, book-recommendation

I would like to read some book, or at least some essential reference papers, about first-order logic where there is no infinite elements in any sense. By example, where the "set" of symbols of the formal language is finite, that is, no infinite list of symbols for variables, predicates, functions or constants.

Also, it cannot be any kind of infinity in the metalanguage or the methods used to "prove" metatheorems.

EDIT: some trolls downvoted this completely correct question by no reasons at all.

Comment: Presumably, you also want there to be only a finite number of well-formed formulas. I think that is unfortunate, because it disagrees with our intuitions about natural language: what is the longest English sentence? You should look into [ultrafinitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafinitism) but I don't think many people think it Is a helpful take on mathematics.

Comment: @Rob there is a longer English sentence, as our existence is finite in all aspects, however we can't evaluate what is this finite number

Comment: I think you meant "longest" rather than "longer". And I disagree with your statement that "our existence is finite in all aspects": we are able to contemplate the infinite, and mathematics is just contemplation (that has an amazing impact on the real world).

Comment: @Rob we can't *contemplate* the infinity, we can *assume* it existence, as a jump of faith. The difference is very important, is the difference between reality and fantasy.

Comment: I don't think you understand the meaning of the English word "contemplate".

Comment: Can you clarify what your goals are? Why do you want to read such a book? To be able to *use* first-order logic as a foundation for mathematics, you don't need any infinite sets. Just pick up any logic book, read the section on syntax and proof-rules of first-order logic (ignoring semantics), and insert the word "finite" everywhere a set is mentioned. Assuming you're comfortable with finite sets and finite sequences of symbols, this is enough to write formal proofs. Who needs metatheorems?

Answer (score 2):

[Here is](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.31.3918) as paper on a formal system for "feasible" numbers. As Alex Kruckman suggests, the paper often just refers to existing theory on formal logic for background. The main novel requirement is that all deductions must be cut-free, in terms of sequent calculus. Aside from that, there are limitations on the number of symbols allowed to occur in a term and such.

The axioms are various ordinary arithmetic statements, plus:

$$∀n. \lfloor\log_2 \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor \rfloor < 10$$

I.E. every number $n$ is less than $2^{1024}$. Because of the rules of the proof system, any contradiction derivable from this assumption would require too large of a proof to actually write down. So, it is practically consistent.

Comment: Very interesting.